# Microsoft Visual Basic (Checkbox relationships)

Tags: vba, checkbox

I have a problem :)

I am working in Microsoft Word 2013 right now. I made four checkboxes: "A", "B" 
, "C" and "D". My wish is that there is a relationship between the checkboxes. So if I check "A" then I want that "B" and "C" are also automatically checked. And if I check "B" I want that "C" is also automatically checked. When I check "C" then I want that just "C" is checked. And if I check "D" then only "D" needs to be checked.

I already found the next code:

```
Sub SelectAll_Click()  
Dim CB As CheckBox  
For Each CB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes  
  If CB.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Name Then  
    CB.Value = ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value  
  End If  
Next CB  
End Sub  

Sub Mixed_State()  
Dim CB As CheckBox  
For Each CB In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes  
  If CB.Name <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Name And CB.Value <> ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value And ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value <> 2 Then  
    ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = 2  
Exit For  
   Else  
     ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 1").Value = CB.Value  
  End If  
Next CB  
End Sub
```

This works for me in Excel, but not in Word (I get an error). But the main issue is that by this code all of the checkboxes are selected. That's not exactly what 
I want.

I hope it is clear what I'm asking for and I hope you can help me out.

Thanks!

Kind regards.

Comment: What should happen  if A, B, C are checked and A becomes unchecked - should B an C become unchecked as well? Or other combinations (2 of them checked, 2 unchecked) and their status changes either way?

Comment: You are most likely getting an error with MS-Word because Word doesn't have sheets, hence `ActiveSheet` isn't declared. Regarding your desired behavior, if they're just 4 checkboxes, you probably don't even need a For loop.

Comment: @paulbica 

Thanks for you response. 

For example:
___Scenario one:_______ 
1. You select "A", "B" and "C"
2. You unselect "A"
3. It's possible
__Scenario two:___________
1. You select "A", "B" and "C"
2. You unselect "B"
3. Then "A" is also automatically unselected
___Scenario three:___________
1. You select "A", "B" and "C"
2. You unselect "C"
3. Then "A" and "B" are also automatically unselected.
___________

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed

Also thanks for your response. 

- Do you know how I can use this code in MS Word? 

The code above is just an example. In my document I have more checkboxes and the checkboxes have other names.


Is my wish very difficult to realize? 

Regards

Comment: start macro recorder, insert a four checkboxes, check and uncheck some then stop recorder and examine the resulting code. .... come back with furtther questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer (code), for anyone else in the same situation. The checkboxes have a lot of relationships with each other. I have 13 checkboxes.

```
Private Sub Q1A_Click()
   If Q1A.Value = True Then
      Q1B.Value = True
      Q1C.Value = True
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1B_Click()
   If Q1B.Value = True Then
      Q1C.Value = True    
   ElseIf Q1B.Value = False Then
      Q1A.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1C_Click()
   If Q1C.Value = False Then
      Q1B.Value = False
      Q1A.Value = False
      Q1D.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1D_Click()
   If Q1D.Value = True Then
      Q1C.Value = True
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1E_Click()
   If Q1E.Value = True Then
      Q1F.Value = True
      Q1G.Value = True
      Q1H.Value = True
      Q1I.Value = True
      Q1J.Value = True
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1F_Click()
   If Q1F.Value = True Then
      Q1G.Value = True
   ElseIf Q1F.Value = False Then
      Q1E.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1G_Click()
   If Q1G.Value = False Then
      Q1F.Value = False
   ElseIf Q1G.Value = False Then
      Q1E.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1H_Click()
   If Q1H.Value = True Then
      Q1I.Value = True
      Q1J.Value = True
   ElseIf Q1H.Value = False Then
      Q1E.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1I_Click()
   If Q1I.Value = True Then
      Q1J.Value = True
   ElseIf Q1I.Value = False Then
      Q1H.Value = False
      Q1E.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1J_Click()    
   If Q1J.Value = False Then
      Q1I.Value = False
      Q1H.Value = False
      Q1E.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q2A_Click()
   If Q2A.Value = True Then
      Q2B.Value = True
      Q2C.Value = True
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q2B_Click()
   If Q2B.Value = True Then
      Q2C.Value = True
   ElseIf Q2B.Value = False Then
      Q2A.Value = False    
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q2C_Click()
   If Q2C.Value = False Then
      Q2B.Value = False
      Q2A.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1A_Click()
   If Q1A.Value = True Then
      Q1B.Value = True
      Q1C.Value = True
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1B_Click()
   If Q1B.Value = True Then
      Q1C.Value = True    
   ElseIf Q1B.Value = False Then
      Q1A.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1C_Click()
   If Q1C.Value = False Then
      Q1B.Value = False
      Q1A.Value = False
      Q1D.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1D_Click()
   If Q1D.Value = True Then
      Q1C.Value = True
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1E_Click()
   If Q1E.Value = True Then
      Q1F.Value = True
      Q1G.Value = True
      Q1H.Value = True
      Q1I.Value = True
      Q1J.Value = True
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1F_Click()
   If Q1F.Value = True Then
      Q1G.Value = True
   ElseIf Q1F.Value = False Then
      Q1E.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1G_Click()
   If Q1G.Value = False Then
      Q1F.Value = False
   ElseIf Q1G.Value = False Then
      Q1E.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1H_Click()
   If Q1H.Value = True Then
      Q1I.Value = True
      Q1J.Value = True
   ElseIf Q1H.Value = False Then
      Q1E.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1I_Click()
   If Q1I.Value = True Then
      Q1J.Value = True
   ElseIf Q1I.Value = False Then
      Q1H.Value = False
      Q1E.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q1J_Click()
   If Q1J.Value = False Then
      Q1I.Value = False
      Q1H.Value = False
      Q1E.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q2A_Click()
   If Q2A.Value = True Then
      Q2B.Value = True
      Q2C.Value = True
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q2B_Click()
   If Q2B.Value = True Then
      Q2C.Value = True
   ElseIf Q2B.Value = False Then
      Q2A.Value = False
   End If
End Sub

Private Sub Q2C_Click()
   If Q2C.Value = False Then
      Q2B.Value = False
      Q2A.Value = False
   End If
End Sub
```